# Dynamically add Script to a Dynamically Created Div at Runtime vb.net aspx

Tags: asp.net

I have created a web form with a Parent `div` container that contains child `div`s based on an SQL query. The number of children is based on the number of rows in the query result. I am hitting a snag though, and I think it's because I am programmatically adding a script as the `div`s are created. I know the script works because I tested it. It just isn't firing for the dynamically created divs.

Here is what the code looks like in the child div. It works, but not on dynamically created `div`s.

```
Sub ThumbView()

    lbl_Status.Text = "ThumbView"

    ListPanel.Visible = False
    Dim MyTable As String = "[Estimate_Info4]"
    Dim Sql As String = "SELECT* FROM [Estimate_Info4]"
    Dim dbConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
    Dim dbCommand = New SqlCommand(Sql, dbConnection)
    Dim data As New SqlDataAdapter(dbCommand)
    Dim table As New DataTable(MyTable)
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

    '//////////Open Database Connection////////////

    dbConnection.Open()
    data.Fill(table)

    '//////////Loop through Data & Create Div for each Record //////////////


    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
        For i As Integer = 0 To (table.Rows.Count - 1)
            Try
                rowIndex = i

                '/////////////////Control Delcarations/////////////////////

                Dim NumberName As String = CStr(table.Rows(rowIndex)("EstNumber")) & " " & CStr(table.Rows(rowIndex)("JobName"))
                Dim CleanName As String = RemoveWhitespace(NumberName)
                Dim LBL_EstId As Label = New Label
                Dim LBL_EstNumber As Label = New Label
                Dim LBL_EstName As Label = New Label
                Dim LBL_EstAddress1 As Label = New Label
                Dim LBL_EstAddress2 As Label = New Label
                Dim LineBreak As HtmlGenericControl = New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("br")
                Dim LineBreak1 As HtmlGenericControl = New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("br")
                Dim LineBreak2 As HtmlGenericControl = New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("br")
                Dim LineBreak3 As HtmlGenericControl = New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("br")
                Dim LineBreak4 As HtmlGenericControl = New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("br")
                Dim LineBreak5 As HtmlGenericControl = New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("br")
                Dim div As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl("div")
                Dim divleft As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl("div")
                Dim divright As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl("div")
                Dim MyScript As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl("Script")
                Dim MyIMG As ImageButton = New ImageButton
                Dim MyIMG2 As ImageButton = New ImageButton
                Dim RecID As Integer = (table.Rows(rowIndex)("Id"))
                Dim RecID2 As String = CStr(table.Rows(rowIndex)("Id"))



                '/////////////////Add 1st Child Div//////////////////

                div.Attributes.Add("runat", " = server")
                div.Style.Add("Class", "test")
                div.Style.Add("width:", "637px")
                div.Style.Add("height:", "228px")
                div.Style.Add("aria-multiline", "True")
                div.Style.Add("font-family", "verdana")
                div.Style.Add("aria-multiline", "True")
                div.Style.Add("word-break", "break-all")
                div.Style.Add("word-wrap", "break-word")
                div.Style.Add("Padding", "100x")
                div.Style.Add("Border", "thick solid #666666")
                div.Style.Add("margin-bottom", "10px")
                div.Style.Add("margin-top", "10px")
                div.Style.Add("margin-right", "10px")
                div.Style.Add("margin-left", "10px")
                div.Style.Add("display", "inline-grid")

                Panel1.Style.Add("display", "inherit")
                Panel1.Controls.Add(div)


                '/////////////////Add 1st Child to First Child Div Float Left to house Image//////////////////

                Dim StartString As String = "<script language=" & Chr(34) & "vb" & Chr(34) & "runat=" & Chr(34) & "server" & Chr(34) & ">" & Chr(10)
                Dim EndString As String = "Sub ImageBttn" & RecID & "_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageBttn" & RecID & ".Click" & Chr(10) &
                "Dim JobName As String = ImageBttn" & RecID & ".DescriptionUrl" & Chr(10) & "Dim JobID As String = ImageBttn" & RecID2 & ".CommandName" & Chr(10) &
                "Response.Redirect(String.Format(" & Chr(34) & "~/476.aspx?JobName={0}&JobID={1}" & Chr(34) & ", JobName, JobID))" & Chr(10) & "End Sub" '& Chr(10) & "</script>"
                ' Dim inputString As String = EndString.Replace((Char)34),"").ToString()
                'MsgBox(StartString & EndString)

                Dim Q As String = Chr(34).ToString
                Dim aString As String = Q & "~/476.aspx?JobName={0}&JobID={1}" & Q & ", JobName, JobID))"
                Dim mymsg As String = "You Clicked" & NumberName

                Dim folderPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Files/VBScripts/")
                Dim Mypath As String = folderPath & CleanName & ".vbs"
                Try
                    'Check whether Directory (Folder) exists.
                    If Not Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then
                        'If Directory (Folder) does not exists Create it.
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
                    End If
                    'Save the File to the Directory (Folder).
                    'Dim Path As String = Server.MapPath("~/Files/VBScripts/")


                    Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(Mypath)

                    ' Add text to the file.
                    Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(EndString)
                    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
                    fs.Close()


                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("Something has gone wrong..." & vbNewLine & ex.Message)

                End Try


                MyIMG.Style.Add("ID", CleanName)
                MyIMG.Style.Add("Runat", "server")
                MyIMG.Style.Add("OnClick", "ImageBttn" & RecID & "_Click")
                MyIMG.Style.Add("DiscriptionUrl", NumberName)
                MyIMG.Style.Add("CommandName", RecID2)
                MyIMG.Style.Add("Class", "inner")

                ' /////////////// Create VBScript File and Add to Div////////////////

                MyScript.Attributes.Add("script language", "vb")
                MyScript.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
                MyScript.Attributes.Add("src", MyPath)


                ' src="
                divleft.Attributes.Add("runat", " = server")
                divleft.Style.Add("Class", "inner")
                divleft.Style.Add("width: ", "186px")
                divleft.Style.Add("height:", "228px")
                divleft.Style.Add("aria-multiline", "True")
                divleft.Style.Add("font-family", "verdana")
                divleft.Style.Add("aria-multiline", "True")
                divleft.Style.Add("Padding", "100x")
                divleft.Style.Add("Border", "1px Gray")
                divleft.Style.Add("Float", "Right")
                divleft.Style.Add("display", "inline-Block")
                divleft.Controls.Add(MyScript)

                div.Controls.Add(divleft)

                '/////////////////Add 2nd Child to First Child Div Float Right to house Labels//////////////////

                divright.Attributes.Add("runat", " = server")
                divright.Style.Add("Class", "inner")
                divright.Style.Add("width:", "351px")
                divright.Style.Add("height:", "228px")
                divright.Style.Add("aria-multiline", "True")
                divright.Style.Add("font-family", "verdana")
                divright.Style.Add("aria-multiline", "True")
                divright.Style.Add("Padding", "100x")
                divright.Style.Add("Border", "1px Gray")
                divright.Style.Add("Float", "Left")


                divright.Style.Add("display", "inline")
                div.Controls.Add(divright)

                '/////////////////Add Controls to all of the Children//////////////////

                MyIMG.Style.Add("ID", CleanName)
                MyIMG.Style.Add("Runat", "server")
                MyIMG.Style.Add("DiscriptionUrl", NumberName)
                MyIMG.Style.Add("CommandName", RecID2)
                MyIMG.Style.Add("Class", "inner")
                MyIMG.Style.Add("OnClick", "ImageBttn" & RecID & "_Click")
                divleft.Controls.Add(MyIMG)
                MyIMG.ImageUrl = "~/Images/BLDG1.jpg"




                LBL_EstNumber.Style.Add("runat", "server")
                LBL_EstNumber.Style.Add("Height", "21px")
                LBL_EstNumber.Style.Add("Width", "266px")
                LBL_EstNumber.Style.Add("Font-Names", "Verdana")
                LBL_EstNumber.Style.Add("Font-Size", "medium")
                LBL_EstNumber.Style.Add("Font-Bold", "True")
                LBL_EstNumber.Style.Add("ForeColor", "#666666")
                LBL_EstNumber.Text = Chr(10) & "  " & CStr(table.Rows(rowIndex)("EstNumber")) & " "
                divright.Controls.Add(LineBreak1)
                divright.Controls.Add(LBL_EstNumber)
                LBL_EstNumber.Font.Bold = True


                LBL_EstName.Style.Add("runat", "server")
                LBL_EstName.Style.Add("Height", "21px")
                LBL_EstName.Style.Add("Width", "266px")
                LBL_EstName.Style.Add("Font-Names", "Verdana")
                LBL_EstName.Style.Add("Font-Size", "medium")
                LBL_EstName.Style.Add("Font-Bold", "True")
                LBL_EstName.Style.Add("ForeColor", "#666666")
                LBL_EstName.Text = Chr(10) & "  " & CStr(table.Rows(rowIndex)("JobName")) & "   "
                divright.Controls.Add(LineBreak2)
                divright.Controls.Add(LBL_EstName)
                LBL_EstName.Font.Bold = True

                LBL_EstAddress1.Style.Add("runat", "server")
                LBL_EstAddress1.Style.Add("Height", "21px")
                LBL_EstAddress1.Style.Add("Width", "266px")
                LBL_EstAddress1.Style.Add("Font-Names", "Verdana")
                LBL_EstAddress1.Style.Add("Font-Size", "Small")
                LBL_EstAddress1.Style.Add("ForeColor", "666666")
                LBL_EstAddress1.Text = CStr(table.Rows(rowIndex)("JobAddress"))
                divright.Controls.Add(LineBreak3)
                divright.Controls.Add(LBL_EstAddress1)

                LBL_EstAddress2.Style.Add("runat", "server")
                LBL_EstAddress2.Style.Add("Height", "21px")
                LBL_EstAddress2.Style.Add("Width", "266px")
                LBL_EstAddress2.Style.Add("Font-Names", "Verdana")
                LBL_EstAddress2.Style.Add("Font-Size", "Small")
                LBL_EstAddress2.Style.Add("ForeColor", "666666")
                LBL_EstAddress2.Text = CStr(table.Rows(rowIndex)("JobCity")) & ", " & CStr(table.Rows(rowIndex)("JobState")) & " " & CStr(table.Rows(rowIndex)("JobZipCode"))
                divright.Controls.Add(LBL_EstAddress2)
                divright.Controls.Add(LineBreak4)

                MyIMG2.Style.Add("runat", "server")
                divright.Controls.Add(MyIMG2)

                Dim EstStatus As Integer = (table.Rows(rowIndex)("EstimateStatus"))

                If EstStatus = 2 Then MyIMG2.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Loss.jpg"
                If EstStatus = 3 Then MyIMG2.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Awarded.jpg"
                If EstStatus = 1 Then MyIMG2.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Pending.jpg"


            Catch Ex As Exception
                MsgBox("We've encountered an error; " & Ex.Message)
            End Try

        Next

    Next
    '/////////////////unhide the parent//////////////

    Panel1.Style.Add("Height", "800px")
    Panel1.Style.Add("width", "1800px")
    Panel1.Style.Add("overflow", "scroll")
    Panel1.Style.Add("overflow-y", "Scroll")
    Panel1.Style.Add("overflow-x", "scroll")
    Panel1.Visible = True

End Sub

'end result
```

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/BLDG1.jpg" OnClientClick="ImageButton4_Click" DescriptionUrl="EST 02 Concrete Superstructure Hotel" EnableTheming="True" />
            
         <script language="vb" runat="server">
             Sub ImageButton4_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton4.Click
                 Dim JobName As String = ImageButton4.DescriptionUrl
                 Dim JobID As String = ImageButton4.CommandName
                 Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/476.aspx?JobName={0}&JobID={1}", JobName, JobID))
             End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: would not a gridview, listview or even a repeater be a better choice? You define that repeater, and then send it data from the query. You find much less code is required, and you can attached one event and have it operate on the "row" of that repeater.

Comment: I originally coded this as a grid, but it looked dated. I then dynamically listed the jobs as menu items, looked ok, but still not the rich interaction I want to achieve. I want to give the end user the option of Thumbs or List with Icons that indicate status of the job. Which I have done, Also I like the shadow effect of mouseover the divs.  I went a Different route  cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName, csText.ToString())  -  the code block shows up on the page but isn't firing :(

Comment: Bootstrap is included in near all .net templates by default. You add cssclass="table table-hover" to a grid, and they look fantastic.  Look + feel is a non issue. Using code will look even worse to build that markup anyway. As you need more custom layout, then I use a listview as opposed to a gridview. Better is each asp.net control dropped into the lv does not need a itemtempate to surround that control. For repeating data - pick the right control - it will repeat for you, and attempting to loop code + spit out markup is really difficult and takes too much code, and will not look better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not write all that code to inject repeating data into a web page. It not only too much code, but then after you done that, then trying to pluck out, or have the user operate against a given row of data is too much work.

I suggest you create ONE thing, lay it out correct in the desinger, and then simply feed it data.

So, say we have this:

[image]

So create the "one thing", lay it out nice. style it - do whatever. The result is simple, no code, use markup - you are done.

Now, look how easy it now becomes to "repeat" the data over and over with this code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' load the Repeater
        LoadData
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadData()

    Using cmdSQL As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName",
                                 New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        Repeater1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        Repeater1.DataBind()

    End Using

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Now, was that not oh so easy? And then we can add css, get fancy, and improve that grid, but NOT have to touch the code behind!!!

And now, it becomes SUPER easy to deal with one thing. For example, we have that button click in the div. Lets get the row clicked, get the database PK id, and lets shove that into a label FOR THE ONE repeater item.

The code is thus this:

```
Protected Sub cmdTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' btn click 

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim rRow As RepeaterItem = btn.Parent
    Dim str As String = "Row Clicked = " & rRow.ItemIndex & " (PK ID = " & btn.Attributes.Item("PKID") & ")<br/>"

    Dim txtHotel As TextBox = rRow.FindControl("txtHotel")

    str &= "Hotel name = " & txtHotel.Text

    ' now setup label 
    Dim lbl As Label = rRow.FindControl("Label1")
    lbl.Text = str
End Sub
```

I mean, how easy was that? So if we click on the 3nd one, we see this:

[image]

So, put your repeating stuff into of al things a "repeater".

Note how easy, how clean, how little code was written, and yet we get amazing ability here.

So, I recommend that you move out your code from the vb side, put it into a single nice layout, and then just shove data into that repeater - and it will "repeat" the data for you over and over.

Don't hard code all that markup in VB - it too much work, too hard, and costs too much time to get things done.

Edit:
So we use this code to load:

```
Sub LoadData()

    Using cmdSQL As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotels  ORDER BY HotelName",
                                 New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        Dim rst As New DataTable
        rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        Repeater1.DataSource = rst
        Repeater1.DataBind()

    End Using

End Sub
```

We used a datatable - since we need it later.

Now our row data bind event to change the status button is this:

```
Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound

    Select Case e.Item.ItemType.ToString

        Case "Item", "AlternatingItem"

            Dim btnImage As ImageButton = e.Item.FindControl("cmdStatus")

            Select Case e.Item.DataItem("Status")
                Case 1
                    btnImage.ImageUrl = "Content/ok.png"
                Case 2
                    btnImage.ImageUrl = "Content/ckdelete.png"
                Case 3

            End Select

        Case "Footer"

    End Select

End Sub
```

our markup is this:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
     <div style="float:left;width:auto;border:solid;border-width:2px;padding:15px;margin-right:20px;border-radius:25px;box-shadow: 5px 5px #888888">
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <img src="Content/Skyline.PNG" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="txtHotel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="txtAD" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address") %>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            Active :<asp:CheckBox ID="Active" runat="server"      Checked ='<%# Eval("Active") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
            <asp:Button ID="cmdTest" runat="server" Text="Row Click" OnClick="cmdTest_Click"
                PKID = '<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                />
            <br />
            <div style="float:left">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdStatus" runat="server" ImageUrl="Content/ok.png" Height="20px" Width="20px"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Output:

[image]

The beauty of above? We can now click on that button, or even the lower left check box - and we now have a simple event button code behind to grab that row - we can now show or launch another page based on clicking on each item.

Note how it took me less then 5 minutes to change my layout - that's because I am NOT writing code to do that layout and the mark-up part. So it was super easy for me to change the layout - even adding the graphic image.

Comment: That Did the trick. I have never used the data repeater before. Invaluable lesson. Thanks Albert

Comment: All good. Note close how the button event (and could be image button) have a event, and then the event uses btn.Parent to pick up the repeater row - and note how in the test button I passed the PKID from the database - both handy tricks.  Note that you can't just double click on a button in the repeater to auto-wire up the event code, but just type in OnClick=     (when you hit "=" sign, then choose create new event - it don't seem like anything occurred - but flip to code behind and you see the button event stub.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm going another route and the code is not firing.
I know there are easier ways to do this- So I'm adding a photo of webapps thumb view-there is also a list view view with icons indicating status. All I need now is the code to fire-It shows up on the page when I inspect.

![webform view]: (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmmK5IyEVLSlg9gQSd_eb5KzA8UVcg?e=8sSdvI)

` Try

```
                    Dim csName As [String] = "ClientScript" & RecID
                    Dim csType As Type = divleft.[GetType]()
                    Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
                    If Not cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csType, csName) Then
                        Dim csText As New StringBuilder()
                        csText.Append("<script language=" & Chr(34) & "vb" & Chr(34) & "runat=" & Chr(34) & "server" & Chr(34) & ">")
                        csText.Append("Sub ImageBttn" & RecID & "_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageBttn" & RecID & ".Click" & Chr(10) &
               "Dim JobName As String = ImageBttn" & RecID & ".DescriptionUrl" & Chr(10) & "Dim JobID As String = ImageBttn" & RecID2 & ".CommandName" & Chr(10) &
                "Response.Redirect(String.Format(" & Chr(34) & "~/476.aspx?JobName={0}&JobID={1}" & Chr(34) & ", JobName, JobID))" & Chr(10) &
                "msgbox(ImageBttn" & RecID & ".DescriptionUrl)" & Chr(10) & "End Sub" & Chr(10) & "</script>")
                        cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName, csText.ToString())
                    End If

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("Something has gone wrong..." & vbNewLine & ex.Message)

                End Try``
```

Comment: that screen shot is a perfect example for a repeater. You can have the repeater go across the page. For formatting, use the row data bound event to change button color etc. Still going  to be way less code.

Comment: see my edit in my answer - note how I was easily able to make the format with the image and change the layout with great ease. In less then 5 minutes, I now have a repeater with the image, and even a status button in the lower left corner. And when it comes time to clicking on each individual item then I can with great ease get the database PK and other information - all again with VERY little code. If you inject the divs, then management of each row/item click is going to be panful. See my NEW screen shots in my answer.